# Two fragments in one Activity, proportions

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have two fragments. When I start the Activity only `list_fragment` is added to the `container` it takes 100% of the screen. Now I want to add the `new_fragment` to the same container. `list_fragment` should take 80% of the screen and `new_fragment` should take 20% of it (the rest).

list_fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#b6b6b6">


  <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listViewRecs"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

new_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

container:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
  >

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For propotions in `LinearLayout` android suggests using [Layout Weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

To achieve it you should set `list_fragment` `layout_weight` to 8, and `new_fragment` `layout_weight` to 2.